# How to Insert a Line Break in a String for Word Document generation Using docx-stamper?

Tags: java, ms-word

I'm working with docx-stamper in Java to generate Word documents and I've hit a snag with inserting line breaks. I've tried using \n, \r\n, and other common escape sequences in my strings, but none of these have resulted in actual line breaks in the output document. Is there a specific way to encode line breaks in strings that docx-stamper will recognize and correctly translate into the document? Any advice or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/thombergs/docx-stamper/blob/master/src/test/java/org/wickedsource/docxstamper/LineBreakReplacementTest.java which contains the following code:

```
    NameContext context = new NameContext();
    DocxStamperConfiguration config = new DocxStamperConfiguration();
    config.setLineBreakPlaceholder("#");
    InputStream template = getClass().getResourceAsStream("LineBreakReplacementTest.docx");
    WordprocessingMLPackage document = stampAndLoad(template, context, config);
```

So it looks like you can choose a character (or string?) you wish to use as a  LineBreakPlaceholder, then leave it up to docx-stamper to do the rest.